# Find initial investment of A.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A, Band C enter into a partnership by investing in the ratio of 3 : 2:
>   4. After 1 year, B invests another Rs. 2,70,000 and C, at the end of 2 years, also invests Rs.2,70,000. At the end of three years, profits
>   are shared in the ratio of 3 : 4 : 5. Find initial investment of A.

Let the initial investments of A, Band C be Rs. 3x, Rs. 2x and Rs. 4x respectively.
But I have confused seeing a [solution](http://www.placementadda.com/placement-study/arithmetic-aptitude/index.php?page=2&ipp=5&c=14).

can you  explain  plz?

Comment: What kind of number is 2,70,000? Is that supposed to be 2,700,000? or 270,000? or is there something special about Rs that means you need those commas where they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The criterions for calculating the apportionment is the duration and amount of the investment.

For example, the expression for B: $[(2x \cdot 12) + (2x + 270000) \cdot 24]$

In the first year (12 months) B invest only the half of A: $4x / 2 \cdot 12$ (first part)

In the next two years (24 months) B invest 270,000 in addition. (second part)

The total amount of the investment is $9x (= 2x +3 x +4 x)$. Thus x is the ninth part of the overall investment of A, B and C.

greetings,

calculus